# FancyBox 2.1.0: Close button not displaying with video in iframe with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, fancybox

Using fancybox 2.1.0, the close button is not displaying under IE9 when a video is inside the content

HTML CODE

```
<a class="fancybox.iframe fancyframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17221844">Iframe vimeo</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancyframe").fancybox({
    type        : 'iframe',
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
```

It works great with other modern browsers

Thanks for helping

Comment: what do you mean with `...when a video is inside the content` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that this is jQuery 1.8 / IE9 bug and it has already been reported - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12266

The temporary solution would be to use older jQuery version (1.7.2).

(You can try yourself - http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9HH5/)